# number of matrices with a single nullspace point

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Suppose I fix a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$. I want to count the number of maximal rank (in this case $n-1$) linearly independent matrices $A_1,\ldots,A_m$ for which  $v$ lies in the nullspace of $all$ the $A_i$s, i.e., $A_iv=0$. What is the largest $m$ for which these set of matrices can exist?

Answer (score 0):

If $Av=0, Bv=0$ then clearly $(A+B)v = Av+Bv=0$ and for any
constant $k$,   $(kA)v = 0$. This shows that the number of such matrices is infinite. Better question would be: How many *Linearly independent* matrices $A$ exist such that $Av=0$ for a fixed vector $v$?

Comment: You are right! edited now.. i wants Ais to be linearly independent...